# Deleting all comment data from WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I have deleted all the comments from my WordPress site using SQL Commands, both wp_comments & wp_commentmeta are empty.

This has deleted all the comments but the problem I currently have is it's still displaying the old comment number using: `<?php comments_number('0 Comments','1 Comment','% Comments'); ?>`

For example a post will still have: "4 Comments" displayed even though those comments don't exist.

Any thoughts on what to do to sort this out?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the comment_count field in wp_posts to '0' as well - it stores it in that table so it doesn't have to do the counts from the comments tables every time....

EDIT (based on comment):

You can run a very simple query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
set comment_count = 0
```

Be careful :) this doesn't have a where clause (a filter) so there is no going back once you do this. It's going to update all your posts to have the comment count to be '0'. If you can make a backup of your DB, that would be good.

Also, depends on what tool you are using to run the query, you may need to put the DB name:

```
UPDATE yourdbname.wp_posts
set comment_count = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, don't suppose you're familiar with SQL? Would be great if you know how to mass do this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not advise removing directly from the database. As data may have dependencies one might end up with orphan records. That may have been your case.

Next time, if one intends to delete a comment from a post, with the post ID (add it in `ADDPOSTID`), save the script bellow and add the PHP file in the root of your WordPress website, login as Admin and call the file directly on your browser:

```
<?php

require('./wp-load.php');

if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    if ( $comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => ADDPOSTID ) ) ) {
        foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
            echo '<p>Deleting comment '.$comment->comment_ID.'</p>';
            wp_delete_comment( $comment->comment_ID, true );
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>No comments found</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Not allowed</p>';
}
```

This may also help solve the current issue.